# Should I encrypt virtual machines with BitLocker or with hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, encryption

I want to encrypt some virtual machines, it's better to encrypt it inside the guest (via BitLocker for Windows 10 VMs) or with the hypervisor (I'm using VMware Workstation and VirtualBox) encryption functionality?

My concerns are about performance and virtual disk size.

Comment: VMware on your desktop or as a real virtualization solution?

Comment: @Seth: VMware Workstation. Isn't it a _real_ virtualization solution?

Comment: It is but there is a difference between VSphere/Hyper-V and VirutalBox/Workstation. The latter means your Hypervisor is running on your OS which takes a bit more abstraction and performance. In addition it means it's easier to leverage your OS level encryption. Essentially with this you have three points that could offer encryption: The OS you're running the virtualization solution one, the guest OS itself and the virtualization solution itself. It shouldn't matter all that much in this case. Do you expect a lot of data operations in those guests?